# DataBricks: dbutils.notebook.run() fails with job aborted but running the notebook individually works

Tags: databricks

I have a notebook that runs many notebooks in order, along the lines of:

```
%python
notebook_list = ['Notebook1', 'Notebook2']
    
for notebook in notebook_list:
    print(f"Now on Notebook: {notebook}")
    try:
        dbutils.notebook.run(f'{notebook}', 3600)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
```

When I run this notebook, I get job aborted exceptions amounting to the following:

```
Exceptions:
(1): Task failed while writing rows,
(2): Failed to execute user defined function (SQLDriverLocal$$$Lambda$1707/462935920: (string) => string)
(3): No input widget named effective_dating is defined
```

For #2 -- I have no user defined functions; I only use Spark functions.

For #3 -- The widget seems fine and I take it that it is just calling this as an error too because of the previous errors.

However, if I run `Notebook1` or `Notebook2` (Run all button) individually, they run as expected.

To make matters more intriguing, if I run the loop above for the *second* time, each notebook will run fine; but **only after** I run each individually.

I would like to have a single notebook that runs many notebooks, rather than setup a pipeline to run each individual notebook on its own.

Comment: Did you try using Tasks in Workflow / Jobs?

Comment: Testing now! Thank you for the tip!

Comment: Let me know whether it worked.

Comment: You will have to call the REST Api to trigger Workflows from Data Factory / Synapse.

Comment: Tried again. `dbutils.notebook.run('Notebook1', 3600);` = Fails , both inside the notebook and as a `Workflow/Job`. If I run the notebook on its own, it runs without error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer which is that, `dbutils.notebook.run` will not run widgets in other notebooks, thereby leading to errors in cells that use those widgets.

Comment: did you try adding the parameters in your notebook call?

dbutils.notebook.run("notebook-name", 60, {"argument": "data", "argument2": "data2" })